# Is there something more to do in this tsql query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, northwind

I wrote this  tsql query, an SP that given a product code as input, calculates and prints on the screen the average value of the discount applied to the product in the sold. What can i do to automize(if is it possible) the @productid value given? And what can I do different in the code? The db is Northwind.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedureMean
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @productid INT = 26
SELECT avg(Discount) FROM ProductDiscounted WHERE ProductID=@productid   
END 

or

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedureMean
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @productid INT = 26
SELECT avg(Discount) FROM ProductDiscounted WHERE ProductID=@productid   
END
```

Comment: ?What problem are you havng

Comment: No one till now, I'm asking if can I add someting to my code, just to be more sure and completed

Comment: still baffled by ' What can i do to automize(if is it possible) the @productid value given?' seems a bit physic to me.

Comment: Instead of hard coding `@productid` value, it is better to create a parameter for it,

Comment: How can i parameter it?

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procname @ProductID int AS` and then get rid of the declare. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) might be a logical next stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedureMean
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Discount_mean FLOAT,
        @productid int,
        @Name varchar(40)
SELECT @Discount_mean = avg(discount), @productid=ProductID, @Name=productname FROM ProductDiscounted WHERE ProductID=55 GROUP BY productid, Productname
PRINT 'The average value of the discount applied to the product '+ cast(@Name as varchar(40)) + ' with ID ' + cast(@productid as varchar(40)) + ',in the sold, is: ' + cast(@Discount_mean as varchar(40))

END
```

So, this is how I did till now, someone answer me if there something different I can do.